# Не получается выставить div в строку

Tags: html, css

Вывожу Black + White. red,orange и blue не получается выставить в строку. Да,я знаю что div это блочный елемент,но как тогда это все сделать? как обыграть что бы div был в левой части а остальное в правой части легко и просто?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#black {
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div id="black">
      <p><b>Black</b> + White</p>
      <p>red</p>
      <p>orange</p>
      <p>blue</p>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: можете показать картинку, как должно быть? а то по описанию не понятно что вы хотите получить

Comment: `display: inline-block;` достаточно заменить на `display: flex;`

Comment: добавил картинку как вы просили

Comment: спасибо большое что помогли, флекс сработал как нужно